# NSPredicate Expression Evaluation

Tags: nspredicate

I am trying to evaluate formula using NSPredicate. But if I replace 
&& with || or vice a versa, evaluation fails. Please find code snippet.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   NSString * str = @"( ( 10>5 || 10<5 ) && ('name' BEGINSWITH 'n') 
)";

   NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str];

   BOOL passes = [p evaluateWithObject:nil];
   NSLog(@"passes: %@", passes ? @"yes" : @"no");


   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance.